# In Apache Kafka, are there any standards or common practices around how topics should be named or how topic messages should be structured?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I’m wondering if there are patterns or idioms that are common in the world of Kafka topics and messages, particularly in systems with numerous types of CRUD operations happening against numerous types of resources (e.g. users, products, orders, carts, etc.).

Is it common to include some kind of CRUD verb like “update”, along with the resource name? Is there a namespace structure that works well? (e.g `org.this.that.topicName`)?

Comment: No. There isn't, as long as it's less than about 256 characters. Voting to close question as opinion based. You might be interested in the recent Stackoverflow blog post about async operations and different Kafka event types, however